# How can I write this conditional if statement without duplicating function calls?

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, dry, rest-assured

I'd like to refactor this Java/RestAssured code to remove the if statement altogether

```
if (someCondition) {    
    someRequestSpecification    
        .given()    
        .queryParam(THING, theThing)    
        .queryParam(SPECIAL_THING, anotherThing)    
        .get()
} else {    
    someRequestSpecification    
        .given()    
        .queryParam(THING, theThing)    
        .get()    
}
```

In other words I want to be able to omit the SPECIAL_THING param completely based on a condition but without having to duplicate the .given() code.

Currently I have the code working with the duplicated lines within an if statement but it's ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor like this.

```java
RequestSpecification reSpec = given().queryParam(THING, theThing);
if(condition){
    reSpec.queryParam(SPECIAL_THING, anotherThing);
}
reSpec.get();
```

Comment: Of course, why am I trying to do it all in one go when I can separate it out. Awesome, thanks Lucas